# Python Class. One def get for several attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, iteration

I need help to be more clear how to make my code correctly. Now it's work but I still think the code logic not correct :)
I have one class with several attributes:

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self, player1, player2, player3, player4, score_pair1, score_pair2):
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
        self.player3 = player3
        self.player4 = player4
        self.score_pair1 = score_pair1
        self.score_pair2 = score_pair2
        self.Online_Players_Dict = []
        self.Temp_Players_Dict = []
        self.Temp_import_players = []
```

I have method inside of this class for work with all attributes:

```
   def create_temp_players(self):
        for i in ('player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4'):
            temp = self.__getattribute__(i)
            if not isinstance(temp, Player):
                for ii in self.Temp_import_players:
                    if ii['name'] == self.__getattribute__(i):
                        self.__setattr__(i, Player(self.__getattribute__(i), ii['score'], ii['daily_score']))
                        b = self.__getattribute__(i)
                        a = dict(name=b.name, score=b.score, daily_score=b.daily_score)
                        self.Online_Players_Dict.append(a)
                temp = self.__getattribute__(i)
                if not isinstance(temp, Player):
                    self.__setattr__(i, Player(self.__getattribute__(i)))
                    b = self.__getattribute__(i)
                    a = dict(name=b.name, score=b.score, daily_score=b.daily_score)
                    self.Online_Players_Dict.append(a)
                    self.Temp_Players_Dict.append(a)
```

And everything work correct, but I think not right to use (**getattribute**) and (**setattr**) here. But I can't find other way to correct interaction attributes in the code.
Do you have any idea how to make it better?

PS: Class Player also has attribute:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, score=500, daily_score=0):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.daily_score = daily_score
```

Comment: Put all the players in a list, then you can just loop over it or index it, instead of using `getattr()` and `setattr()`.

Comment: Do you mean like this: for i in (self.player1, self.player2, self.player3, self.player4): ?

Comment: No, I mean `self.players = [player1, player2, player3, player4]`. Then you can use `for player in self.players:` in other methods.

Comment: Ok, but in other part of code I still need use self.player1 self.player2 and so on. Means I need : self.players = [player1, player2, player3,player4] and also keep self.player1 = player1, self.player2 = player2, self.player3 = player3 for other part of code?

Comment: In those other codes you can use `self.players[0]` and `self.players[1]`

Comment: The logic of code is operate with self.playerX. I creating new class Player and bind with each self.playerX by input. Later all operation done by self.player. If I change like you wrote, not sure that I can use other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed code like this

```
for player, i in zip(self.players, (0, 1, 2, 3)):
            if not isinstance(self.players[i], Player):
                for ii in self.Temp_import_players:
                    if ii['name'] == self.players[i]:
                        self.players[i] = Player(self.players[i], ii['score'], ii['daily_score'])
                        a = dict(name=self.players[i].name, score=self.players[i].score, daily_score=self.players[i].daily_score)
                        self.Online_Players_Dict.append(a)
                if not isinstance(self.players[i], Player):
                    self.players[i] = Player(self.players[i])
                    a = dict(name=self.players[i].name, score=self.players[i].score, daily_score=self.players[i].daily_score)
                    self.Online_Players_Dict.append(a)
                    self.Temp_Players_Dict.append(a)
```

Later will refactoring all self.playerX to self.player[X]

Comment: Not clear enough, whether it is answer or a question, If it is a question, edit the question instead of answering. if it is answer, it worked and the issue is with something like that that explains